# Write a program in prolog that determines if there are exactly three values in such a way that they add upto a sum of N

Tags: prolog

Eg:

List[1,2,3,4,5,6] with N equal to 6 should print **true** because there are exactly 3 values that add upto 6. 1+2+3.

List[2,5,7,9] with N equal to 12 should print **false** as there are no 3 elements that add upto 12.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: sumthrees(0,[])
sumthrees(N,[X,Y,Z|T]) :- sumthrees(N,[X,Y,Z|T), N is X+Y+Z.

Comment: Well, I did try a number of times and was unsuccessful. That is why I decided to post here. Anyways, here's how I've been trying to approach the problem. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: The reason people push you to show what you tried already is that it entices answers (you'll get better answers), and that's it sort of etiquette out here as well...
My prolog days are too long ago to remember much about it.

Comment: I am new to this website and posting on forums as well. I was just trying to get better at prolog

Comment: Forgive me for not knowing that.

Comment: Read the online help. It explains the guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: What answer do you expect if the list contains two such triplets? For example: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,1]`, then you have 1+2+3=6 and 2+3+1=6. Should the predicate succeed or fail in that case?

Comment: The predicate should succeed in that case.

I'm sorry. I explicitly mentioned that there are exactly 3 values thinking that there needs to be 3 elements that add up to a certain number but yeah, the predicate needs to be true if there is atleast one such pair that adds up to the given value N

Comment: @lurker I did that. Thank you

Comment: @ScottHunter How about this?

sumthrees([],0).
sumthrees([X|T],[Y|T],[Z|T],N) :- sumthrees([[T|H1],[T|H1],[T|H1]|T],N), N is X+Y+Z, X is N-Y-Z, Y is N-X-Z, Z is N-X-Y.

Comment: @ScottHunter Also, what do you mean by a "helper" version of the predicate? Is it something that goes along sumthrees()?

Comment: @SpaceCow: It doesn't work, for many reasons; if you didn't bother to try it, don't waste my time; if you did, then you should be able to explain the problem (even if you don't know the solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's maybe start with a more general predicate that describes the relation between a list, a sublist of said list and the sum of numbers in the sublist. To make it obvious which argument is what, it is opportune to chose a descriptive name for the predicate, say `sum_ofsub_fromlist/3`. Now let's observe that if the first argument is the sum of the numbers in the sublist, then successively subtracting those numbers from the sum yields zero, e.g.: X=A+B → X-A-B=0. So there will be a base case that contains `0` as the sum and `[]` as the sublist (rule 1)  and a recursive rule that subtracts the elements of the sublist from the sum (rule 2). And since a sublist does not contain all elements of the list it's taken from in general, there will be a recursive rule for skipping elements of the list that do not occur in the sublist (rule 3). This rule is only needed as long as there are still elements in the sublist, so a constraint would be beneficial, that prevents this rule from succeeding once the sublist is empty. These ideas can be realized in Prolog like so:

```
sum_ofsub_fromlist(0,[],_L).             % rule 1
sum_ofsub_fromlist(X,[A|Bs],[A|As]) :-   % rule 2
   X0 is X-A,
   sum_ofsub_fromlist(X0,Bs,As).
sum_ofsub_fromlist(X,Bs,[_A|As]) :-      % rule 3
   dif(Bs,[]),                           % constraint: sublist not empty
   sum_ofsub_fromlist(X,Bs,As).
```

You can query this predicate to assure yourself that it delivers all sublists for the given sum in your examples:

```
?- sum_ofsub_fromlist(6,S,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
S = [1, 2, 3] ;
S = [1, 5] ;
S = [2, 4] ;
S = [6] ;
false.

?- sum_ofsub_fromlist(12,S,[2,5,7,9]).
S = [5, 7] ;
false.
```

Building on this you can then write a calling predicate that only succeeds for sublists of length three:

```
sum_oftriple_fromlist(S,T,L) :-
   T=[_,_,_],                      % T has to be a triple
   sum_ofsub_fromlist(S,T,L).
```

This predicate yields the answers you desire:

```
?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(6,T,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
T = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.

?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(12,T,[2,5,7,9]).
false.
```

Note that the predicate is also working with negative numbers:

```
?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(6,T,[-5,-3,-1,2,4,7,8,9]).
T = [-5, 2, 9] ;
T = [-5, 4, 7] ;
T = [-3, 2, 7] ;
false.

?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(-6,T,[-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,2,4]).
T = [-6, -4, 4] ;
T = [-6, -2, 2] ;
T = [-5, -3, 2] ;
T = [-3, -2, -1] ;
false.
```

However, due to the use of `is/2`, the predicate only works if the first and the third arguments are ground:

```
?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(S,T,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (7) sum_ofsub_fromlist(_G918, [_G1016, _G1019, _G1022], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) ?

?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(6,T,[A,B,C,D,E,F]).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (7) sum_ofsub_fromlist(6, [_G2121, _G2124, _G2127], [_G1945, _G1948, _G1951, _G1954, _G1957, _G1960]) ?
```

If that's fine with you, you can stop here. Alternatively, you could opt to make the predicate more versatile by using [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html). Just apply these minor changes to your code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).               % <- new

sum_oftriple_fromlist(S,T,L) :-
   T=[_,_,_],
   sum_ofsub_fromlist(S,T,L).

sum_ofsub_fromlist(0,[],_L).
sum_ofsub_fromlist(X,[A|Bs],[A|As]) :-
   X0 #= X-A,                                % <- change
   sum_ofsub_fromlist(X0,Bs,As).
sum_ofsub_fromlist(X,Bs,[_A|As]) :-
   dif(Bs,[]),
   sum_ofsub_fromlist(X,Bs,As).
```

Now the above queries deliver answers:

```
?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(S,T,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
S = 6,
T = [1, 2, 3] ;
S = 7,
T = [1, 2, 4] ;
S = 8,
T = [1, 2, 5] ;
.                     % another
.                     % seventeen
.                     % results here
```

The second query, however,  yields residual goals (see [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for details) as results:

```
?- sum_oftriple_fromlist(6,T,[A,B,C,D,E,F]).
T = [A, B, C],
_G2424+A#=6,
C+B#=_G2424 ;
T = [A, B, D],
_G2424+A#=6,
D+B#=_G2424 ;
.
.
.
```

To get actual numbers, you have to restrict the range of the numbers and subsequently label the variables in the list:

```
?- L=[A,B,C,D,E,F], sum_oftriple_fromlist(6,T,L), L ins 1..6, label(L).
L = [1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1],
A = B, B = D, D = E, E = F, F = 1,
C = 4,
T = [1, 1, 4] ;
L = [1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2],
A = B, B = D, D = E, E = 1,
C = 4,
F = 2,
T = [1, 1, 4] ;
.
.
.
```

Possibly you are only interested in lists where every number only appears once:

```
?- L=[A,B,C,D,E,F], all_distinct(L), sum_oftriple_fromlist(6,T,L), L ins 1..6, label(L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3,
D = 4,
E = 5,
F = 6,
T = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5],
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3,
D = 4,
E = 6,
F = 5,
T = [1, 2, 3] ;
.
.
.
```

Or maybe you don't even want to restrict the sum:

```
?- L=[A,B,C,D,E,F], all_distinct(L), sum_oftriple_fromlist(S,T,L), L ins 1..6, label(L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3,
D = 4,
E = 5,
F = S, S = 6,                 % sum = 6
T = [1, 2, 3] ;
.
.
.
L = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6],
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 4,
D = 3,
E = 5,
F = 6,
S = 7,                        % sum = 7
T = [1, 2, 4] ;
.
.
.
```

As you can see the CLP(FD) version of the predicate resembles a true relation as opposed to the non-CLP(FD) version. And of course your example queries yield the same answers with both versions.

Comment: `dif(Bs,[]),` there isn't a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only considers the first 3 items in the list, and not any other combinations.

The most natural way to structure a solution involving a list is to base your recursion on the structure of the list.  So:

1. If the first element of the list (say, X) is to be included in the 3 values that sum to N, we need to find a way to find 2 values in the rest of the list that sum to N-X.
2. If it isn't, just try to solve the problem using the rest of the list.

Note that you may need a "helper" version of your predicate that allows you to add other parameters.  In this case, knowing how many values you need to add up would be helpful.